# Color code e-mail from specific folder (Outlook)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Does anyone know whether it is possible to color code (via the View settings) e-mail based upon which folder the it is in?

I thought I could use the `In folder` property from Outlook. However when I use that property and check it against, for instance, 'External' which is also the name of the e-mail folder in which the e-mail resides. Unfortunately, nothing w.r.t. the layout is changed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, i found that the label "EXTERNAL" is included in the subject. So i set the below criteria and succeed to stand out messages that meet it in the message list:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: No sorry, this solution doesn't work for me since there is no such information in the e-mail